# Whats difference between these two calls: (_){} and (_)=>{}

Tags: dart

what I mean... when I write code in Flutter (Dart) every time I have to call some callbacks sometimes they are: `(_){}` while other times they are: `(_) => {}` .
With or without parameters _ present.
To my knowledge, they should both be called lamda functions; and lambda functions should be other kind of write funtions

Answer (score 3):

1. `(_){}` has [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) `Null Function`
2. `(_) => {}` has [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) `Map Function()` and it is short form (lambda) for

```dart
() {
  return {};
}
```

This variant returns [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/Map-class.html). 
Full example ([dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/54b3c951d9c26adf3ae068b74b59a5dc)):

```dart
typedef SimpleFun = Null Function();
typedef LambdaFun = Map Function();
void main() {
  final SimpleFun simpleFun = (){};
  final LambdaFun lambdaFun = ()=>{};
  print(simpleFun()); // null
  print(lambdaFun()); // {}
}
```

Comment: interesting... now i need to search, in my previus code... this difference, i never noticed it!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

`(_) => _` is a lamba expression.

A lambda function is a small function containing a single expression. It is used to perform a specific task and it can contain only that one expression

While 
`(_) {}` is a function that can take as many expressions as you want to give it.

Hope this answers your question.